# How to position sticky div on the right of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with `position: sticky` inside another div and I want it to stick to the right bottom of the screen, as long as the parent div is on-screen. However, `right: 0` is without any effect when I write this into the CSS. `left: 100%` works, but brings obvious problems with it when the screen is too small as it will then be positioned relative to the screen and scrolling beyond (to the right) will leave the sticky div behind. Instead I would like the div to stay on the bottom right corner of the screen, until the div is scrolled beyond the screen.

Here is my CSS & HTML:

```css
div.text {
  width: 100%;
}
div.data {
  min-width: 1000px;
}
div.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 90%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="text">
<div class="data">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br> 
</div>

<div class="sticky">Sticky</div>

<br><br>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/7dz0y3cL/4/   also thinking why are you using `padding:50px;` for the box? why not increase and decrease the width and height instead.

Comment: in your example `float:right` is working

Comment: @Sheki When I use `float:right` and scroll right on a small screen, the sticky div is not keeping to the right of the screen but remains at it's initial position before the scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code like below:

```css
div.text {
  min-width: 100%; /* added */
  display:inline-block; /* added */
}
div.data {
  min-width: 1000px;
}
div.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  right:0; /* added */
  margin-left:auto; /* push the element to the right */
  background-color: red;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="text">
<div class="data">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br> 
</div>

<div class="sticky">Sticky</div>

<br><br>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there a way, I can also stick the div to the right of the screen, like `position: fixed` would? In this case it is at the very right of the document and only visible on small screens, when one scrolls to the right.

Comment: @EpicOrganicCucumber are you sure you see this in the code above? did your test my code or you added more code to my code and did your tests?

Comment: I tested the preview snippet on Stack Overflow. I also copied the code and tested in my browser (Firefox 73.0.1) with the same results. ‍♂️ What browser are you using?

Comment: @EpicOrganicCucumber show me a screenshot of the *bad* result and how you want it

Comment: [Link to GIF](https://postimg.cc/JyZdgN7g) I would like the sticky div to stay visible, as long as the div is still on-screen, also in horizontal direction.

Comment: @EpicOrganicCucumber it seems there is a bug on Firefox, it works fine in Chrome

Comment: Thank you, I just tested it on both Chrome and Edge and it really seems to be an upstream issue with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your want..

```css
div.text {
  width: 100%;
}
div.data {
  min-width: 1000px;
}
div.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
    <div class="data">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br> 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br> 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br> 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br> 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="sticky">Sticky</div>
    
    <br><br>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! `position: fixed` is not quite what I need in this case, since I want the sticky div to remain in the same position as long as it is within the div, but when the div is scrolled out of the screen the sticky div should go along.